# Using a BroadcastReceiver to update the UI of a childActivity within a Tabactivity

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have an broadcast-receiver that looks like the following within an activity named **childActivity**.

```
 registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
    switch (getResultCode()){
.
.
.
.
.
.
}
     }, new IntentFilter(XYZ));
```

Now I would like to update the main UI thread (a simple textView) within **childActivity** from this broadcast receiver. 
I would normally do something like

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, childActivity.class); 
intent.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
intent.putExtra("parameter",str);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

However, The **childActivity** is loaded in one of the tabs of a **tabActivity**.
How can I update the UI of just the childActivity now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be an easy way to do this. Hence, I created a method in the tabActivity parent that childActivity called.

That way, the intent could be passed to the parent, which modified the state of the loaded tabs. There seems to be no way to directly access the subActivities.